# How to update Latitude and Longitude in gmap in primefaces

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-gmap

I want to update only latitude and longitude on map when lat and long value changes. But for now I have tried to achieve this using button but this is not working also. I don't want to update whole map, I only want to update lat long value in map whenever it changes or new value comes from code. But for now even button code is not working.

JSF page and ManagedBean code is given as follows:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Form1 hello
        <h:form id="form1"> 
            <p:inputText id="lat" value="#{mapBean.lat}"> </p:inputText>
            <p:inputText id="lng" value="#{mapBean.lng}"> </p:inputText>
            <p:commandButton update="gmp" value="button" actionListener="#{mapBean.funx}"></p:commandButton>
            <p:gmap id="gmp" center="#{mapBean.geo}" zoom="15" type="TERRAIN" style="width:600px;height:400px" model="#{mapBean.advancedModel}" >

            </p:gmap>
        </h:form>  
    </h:body>
</html>
```

```java
public class MapBean {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of MapBean
     */
    private final MapModel advancedModel;
    private String geo;
    private Double lat;
    private Double lng;
    private StringBuilder builder;

    public MapBean() {
        geo = "33.572571, 73.055555";
        advancedModel = new DefaultMapModel();
        //Shared coordinates  33.572571, 73.041444
        //33.576021,73.044491
        lat = 33.576021;
        lng = 73.044491;

        LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        //Icons and Data  
        advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "Rawalpindi", null,   "https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_2752125_en_v0"));
//        for (int i = 0; i < advancedModel.getMarkers().size(); i++) {
//        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("marker" + i,    advancedModel.getMarkers().get(i));
//        }
    }

    public MapModel getAdvancedModel() {
        return advancedModel;
    }

    public String getGeo() {
        return geo;
    }

    public void setGeo(String geo) {
        this.geo = geo;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(Double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public void funx(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("ajax funnx");
        builder.append("\"").append(lat).append(",").append(lng).append("\"");
        geo = builder.toString();
        System.out.println("Latitude" + lat + "Longitutde" + lng);
        LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        //Icons and Data  
        advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "Rawalpindi", null, "https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_2752125_en_v0"));
    }
}
```

Error:

```
WARNING:   /index.xhtml @16,91 actionListener="#{mapBean.funx}": java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @16,91 actionListener="#{mapBean.funx}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:818)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MapBean.MapBean.funx(MapBean.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: What's the scope of your bean? Probably should start by getting rid of the `actionListener`, replacing it with an `action` instead (don't forget to remove the `ActionEvent` argument to that method)

Answer (score 0):

For what concerns you current problem, you need to instantiate the *builder* in your constructor

```
public MapBean() {
        geo = "33.572571, 73.055555";
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        ...
}
```